# Installing ubuntu 18.04 on Celeron machine

Tags: drivers

I have a acer aspire one 751 machince. which is runing on Intel Celeron 1.3GHz processor. it is old machine. I like to install Ubuntu 18.04 in this machince.

my machine details:

Processor: intel celeron M743
Graphics: Intel GMA 
Memory: 2GB (planning to add another 2GB) 
Motherboard: Intel GS45
Sound card: Intel 82801IB ICH9 HD Audio Controller
Wifi: Intel WiFi Link 1000 BGN (b/g/n)

kindly let me know if i can install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or not.

thanks in advance.

regards
Sayeed

Comment: Running GNOME will be a pain. Try other light-weight desktop such as MATE or Xfce. And of course buy more RAM.

Comment: I'm running Xubuntu 18.04 64 bit version without much problem on 2GB RAM only sometimes the browser has to be closed to free RAM. Used to run Xubuntu 17.10 32 bit without this problem but migrated to 64 bit cause Ubuntu is scraping 32 bit slowly and there may be software availability problem in the future. Definitely buy more RAM or install Ubuntu Mate/Xubuntu/Lubuntu 32 bit edition. Ubuntu 18.04 is not usable on 2GB RAM.